# check if a record exist in database using spring boot and JPA repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to check whether a record exist in database before I save. If possible I want to check using two fields i.e regno and name. method to be like checkIfRegNoAndNameExists(){}.
my model class

```
@Entity
public class Car {
     @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String regno;
    private String name;
    // getters, setters, ...
}
```

my dao class

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface ProgramDao extends JpaRepository<CarModel, Integer> {
}
```

my service class

```
@Service
public class CarServiceImpl implements ProgramService {
    @Autowired
    private CarDao carDao;
    @Override
    public carModel saveProgram(carModel car) { 
        return carDao.save(program);
    }
}
```

Comment: create a method like
`boolean existsByRegnoAndName(String regno, String name);`
In your repository.

It will return in boolean whether it exists or not.

Answer (score 9):

```
interface ProgramDao extends JpaRepository<CarModel, Integer> {
    boolean existsByRegnoAndName(String regno, String name);
}
```

Comment: When i run this i get an error that cannot find AndName but this already exists in my model class. No property AndName found for type String!

Comment: What JPA version are you using, or what spring boot version if you are using starter.  Query derivation from method name looks strange because it isn't pick up`And` keyword

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `exists` method:

1. Create an object you're looking for and set desired fields.
2. convert it to `Example`.
3. Use repository's `exists` method.

   ```
   CarModel carModel = new CarModel();
   carModel.setRegno(regno);
   carModel.setName(name);
   repo.exists(Example.of(carModel));
   ```

This is a generic way, that does not require creating a bunch of methods in repository.

Comment: I have used this but returns false even when the record is in the database       
       public boolean exists() {
 CarModel carModel = new CarModel();
 carModel.setRegno("DIT:1.1");
 carModel.setName("DIT0101");
 carDao.exists(Example.of(carModel));
 
 if(carDao.exists(Example.of(carModel))==true) {
  System.out.println("this is"+carDao.exists(Example.of(carModel)));
  System.out.println("Method is true");
 return true;
 }else {
  System.out.println("this is"+carDao.exists(Example.of(carModel)));
  System.out.println("Method is false");
  return false;
 }
 }

Comment: @user3736334 so with method in repository and same parameters the result is true?